# Fixed element doesn't move with scroll

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a div:

```
<div id="contactAll" *ngIf="contactArray.length">
    <p>Selected users:</p>
    <p *ngFor="let contact of contactArray">{{contact.firstname}} {{contact.lastname}}</p>
    <button class="btn-submit" (click)="contactAll()">Contact All</button>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
#contactAll{
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
width: 200px;
height: 250px;
border: 2px solid black;
right: 55px;
top: 50%;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Desired functionality: I want the div to be visible at all times and follow the screen as the user scrolls on my page. How do I achieve this?

It was working earlier, but for some reason it isn't anymore. What could the problem be?

EDIT:

The complete HTML file:

```
<div id="searchContainer">
<h2>Your search yielded {{resultCount}} results</h2>
<div id="pagesContainer">
       <span [class.selected]="currentPage == i" *ngFor="let page of searchPages; let i = index" (click)="setPage(i)">{{i+1}}</span>
</div>
<div class="searchPageContainer" *ngFor="let page of searchPages; let i = index">
    <div class="searchPage" *ngIf="currentPage == i">
        <div class="searchResult" *ngFor="let result of page">
                <input #checkbox type="checkbox" (click)="checkProfile(checkbox, result.user)">
                <table align="center">
                    <th id="usercolumn">
                        <ul id="userlist"> 
                            <li class="searchlistitem" id="resultName">&nbsp;{{result?.user.firstname}} {{result?.user.lastname}}</li>
                            <li class="searchlistitem" id="resultEmail">&nbsp;{{result?.user.email}}</li>
                            <li class="searchlistitem" id="resultCity">&nbsp;{{result?.user.city}}</li>
                            <li class="searchlistitem" id="resultBirthday">&nbsp;{{result?.user.birthday | date}}</li>
                            <li class="searchlistitem" id="resultNationality">&nbsp;{{result?.user.nationality}}</li>
                            <li class="searchlistitem" id="resultGender">&nbsp;{{result?.user.gender}}</li>
                            <li class="searchlistitem" id="resultStudy">&nbsp;{{result?.study}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </th>
                    <th id="skillscolumn">
                        <ul id="skillslist">
                            <h2>Skills</h2>
                            <li *ngFor="let skill of result.skills">{{skill}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </th>
                    <th id="languagescolumn">
                        <ul id="languageslist"> 
                            <h2>Languages</h2>
                            <li *ngFor="let language of result.languages">{{language}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </th>
                </table>

            <div id="button-container">
                <button (click)="viewProfile(result.user.userID)"class="btn-submit">View Profile</button>
                <button (click)="sendMail(result.user)" class="btn-submit">Contact</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="pagesContainerBottom">
       <span [class.selected]="currentPage == i" *ngFor="let page of searchPages; let i = index" (click)="setPage(i)">{{i+1}}</span>
</div>
<div id="contactAll" *ngIf="contactArray.length">
    <p>Selected users:</p>
    <p *ngFor="let contact of contactArray">{{contact.firstname}} {{contact.lastname}}</p>
    <button class="btn-submit" (click)="contactAll()">Contact All</button>
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS file:

```
#searchContainer{
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
}

span{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    background-color: white; 
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transition: border-color 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

span:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #1283b4
}

#pagesContainer{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#pagesContainer::-webkit-scrollbar{
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 1em;
}

#pagesContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

}

#pagesContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #19a0da;
    outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}

#pagesContainerBottom {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    height: 40px;
}

#pagesContainerBottom::-webkit-scrollbar{
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 1em;
}

#pagesContainerBottom::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

}

#pagesContainerBottom::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #19a0da;
    outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}

.searchPage{
    width: 700px;
    height: 100%;
}

.searchResult{
    width: 85%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 13px 4px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.searchResult:hover input[type="checkbox"]{
    visibility: visible;
}

.selected {
    background-color: #19a0da;
    outline: none;
}

.searchlistitem{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#button-container{
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
   bottom: 50px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{
    visibility: hidden;
    outline: none;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;

    transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2); /* IE */
    -moz-transform: scale(2); /* FF */
    -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: scale(2); /* Opera */
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
    visibility: visible;
}

#contactAll{
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    right: 55px;
    top: 50%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#userlist, #skillslist, #languageslist{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Demonstration of the problem:

https://gyazo.com/fe9887a25c84c5e88788c7049c47b9df

Comment: Looks like it works to me: https://jsfiddle.net/4uyeb4hd/

Comment: Can you provide some more details of your file?

Comment: @RichardYan I can provide any details you would like. What should I include in the question?

Comment: @Jesper the code you gave us works in a fiddle environment which means there might be other code not working - please provide us with a test of your non-working code

Comment: Possibly parents of this div and their CSS. A screenshot of the webpage on your computer demonstrating the problem may also be helpful.

Comment: @RichardYan Done.

Answer (score 1):

Check your complete CSS file. `#contactAll` is using `position: absolute`, which should be `position: fixed`. The first CSS you provided utilized `position: fixed`, don't know why you changed that.

Comment: There was a comment telling me to change it to `position: absolute`, so I tried that, but it didn't work either. I just forgot to change it back again.

Comment: After changing to `position: fixed`, seems to work on my computer. Probably try moving `#contactAll` outside of its parent, put it directly under `body`.

Comment: I tried to move it out of the `searchContainer` div, but that did not work. I can't really put it under the `body` tag because I'm developing this application using Angular 2.

Comment: Should be working on pure HTML. I'm not familiar with Angular, so I'm sorry that I couldn't provide further help. Adding the [angular] tag was a correct move.

Comment: Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need some sort of animation, where `#contactAll` follows scroll and stops at the boundaries, you can use jQuery and listen for `scroll` event:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elm = $("#contactAll");
  var lastScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  $(document).scroll(function(ev) {
    var currScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var diffScroll = lastScroll - currScroll;
    var currPos = elm.position().top;
    var newPos = currPos + diffScroll;
    if (newPos < 0) newPos = 0;
    if (newPos > $(window).height() - elm.height()) newPos = $(window).height() - elm.height();
    elm.css({
      top: newPos
    });

    lastScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  })

})
```

```css
#contactAll {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  right: 55px;
  top: 50%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 4000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contactAll" *ngIf="contactArray.length">
  <p>Selected users:</p>
  <p *ngFor="let contact of contactArray">{{contact.firstname}} {{contact.lastname}}</p>
  <button class="btn-submit" (click)="contactAll()">Contact All</button>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not really looking for an animation. I just want my div to be in a fixed position in the browser at all times. Also, I'm using Angular 2 to develop my app.

Comment: Well, i saw your screencapture, looks like some `<style>` is overriding `div`'s `position` to `absolute` instead of `fixed`.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I created that GIF before I remembered to change it back to `position: fixed;`. There was a comment telling me to try `position:absolute`. I will update it now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! I have added animations to my components, and in that connection, my component got `transform: translateX(0px)` added to its style. When I remove this, the fixed position works again. I guess I will have to get rid of my animations :-(